# Сравнение 2х методов по времени исполнения

Tags: golang, benchmark

Хочу сравнить какой из 2х методов работают быстрее. 
Как правильно написать benchmark для них?

Answer (score 1):

Простейший бенчмарк для такого случая:

```
func BenchmarkFooVSBar(b *testing.B) {
    b.Run("foo", func(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            foo()
        }
    })
    b.Run("bar", func(b *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            bar()
        }
    })
}
```

Положить в `foobar_test.go` и запускать как `go test -bench .`.

Ссылки:

- https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go
- https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks